# Controller Ajax request Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-4

Hi guys I'm new to CodeIgniter I'm still figuring out things here. So I have a problem about the ajax request it seem that the controller is not accepting the ajax request. I`m using CodeIgniter 4.0 by the way. I have search a lot of material in the internet and YouTube but still nothing works.

So here's the code in the view folder named layout.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="{csrf_header}" content="{csrf_hash}">
    <title>Ajax test</title>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- <form method="post" action="ajaxtest"> -->
    <div>
        <button type="submit" id="test">test Ajax</button>
    </div>
    <!-- </form> -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //var tokenName = $('#token').attr("name");
            //var tokenVal = $("#token").val();
            // alert(tokenName)
            // alert(tokenVal)

            $('#test').on('click', function() {
                // alert('ok');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/ajaxtest",
                    data: {
                        [tokenName]: tokenVal
                    },
                    method: "post",
                    success: function(response) {
                        alert('ok')
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                        alert(err.Message);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And heres the code in controller

```html
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

// defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');


class AjaxController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        if ($this->request->getMethod() == 'post') {
            echo 'post request done, ';


            if ($this->request->isAJAX()) {
                return 'the request is ajax';
            } else {
                return 'the request is not ajax';
            }
        }

        echo view('layout');
    }
}
```

Here`s the code inside the routes.php

```html
<?php

namespace Config;

// Create a new instance of our RouteCollection class.
$routes = Services::routes();

// Load the system's routing file first, so that the app and ENVIRONMENT
// can override as needed.
if (is_file(SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/Routes.php')) {
    require SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/Routes.php';
}

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Router Setup
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Controllers');
$routes->setDefaultController('Home');
$routes->setDefaultMethod('index');
$routes->setTranslateURIDashes(false);
$routes->set404Override();
// $routes->setAutoRoute(true);
// The Auto Routing (Legacy) is very dangerous. It is easy to create vulnerable apps
// where controller filters or CSRF protection are bypassed.
// If you don't want to define all routes, please use the Auto Routing (Improved).
// Set `$autoRoutesImproved` to true in `app/Config/Feature.php` and set the following to true.
//$routes->setAutoRoute(false);

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Route Definitions
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

// We get a performance increase by specifying the default
// route since we don't have to scan directories.
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');

$routes->match(['get', 'post'], 'ajaxtest', 'AjaxController::index');
// $routes->get('ajaxtest', 'AjaxController::index');
// $routes->post('ajaxtest/success', 'AjaxController::success');

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Additional Routing
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * There will often be times that you need additional routing and you
 * need it to be able to override any defaults in this file. Environment
 * based routes is one such time. require() additional route files here
 * to make that happen.
 *
 * You will have access to the $routes object within that file without
 * needing to reload it.
 */
if (is_file(APPPATH . 'Config/' . ENVIRONMENT . '/Routes.php')) {
    require APPPATH . 'Config/' . ENVIRONMENT . '/Routes.php';
}
```

Now what I`m doing here is just trying to test if ajax works and return something. If I uncomment the form tag in the layout file the request works fine but I need the request given by ajax not in the form tag so I wont use it but if  I use the ajax it wont respond anything and there is no error like in ci4 and the jquery. But the weird thing is that when I use post man and send ajax request it works perfectly fine. Can someone point out what I`m missing here?

Comment: echo something iat 1st line of your index also check your network while making ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

Some change in your ajax function.

```
var value1 = 1;
var value2 = "val2";
$.ajax({
  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/ajaxtest",
  data: {
    "key1": value1,
    "key2": value2
  }, // data will be set as key value pair
  method: "post",
  success: function (response) {
    consol.log(response); // to view your response from controller in webbrowser's console
    alert(response.message); // alret response message
    // alert('ok');
  },
  error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
    alert(err.Message);
  }
});
```

Some change in your controller function

```
public function index() {
  $this->load->view('layout');
}
public function ajax()
{
  $data = [];
  if($this->input->post()){
    $data['message'] = 'the request is ajax post';
    $data['data'] = $this->input->post(); // get data from ajax function's data object
  }else{
    $data['message'] = 'the request is not ajax post';
  }
  return response()->json($data);
}
```

Some change in your routes.php

```
// $routes->match(['get', 'post'], 'ajaxtest', 'AjaxController::index');
$routes->get('ajaxtest', 'AjaxController::index');
$routes->post('ajaxtest', 'AjaxController::ajax');
```